# Ubuntu freezes completely on executing this inline asm

Tags: c, x86, kernel-module, inline-assembly

I am trying to check if the VMX hardware extensions are supported by the processor using inline assembly. I have tried the following two ways of doing it:

**Method 1:**

```
int vmx_support(void) {
    int get_vmx_support, vmx_bit;
    asm volatile ("mov $1, %eax");
    asm volatile ("mov $0, %ecx");
    asm volatile ("cpuid");
    asm volatile ("mov %%ecx, %0\n\t":"=r" (get_vmx_support): : "memory"); 

    vmx_bit = (get_vmx_support >> 5) & 1;
    if (vmx_bit == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
int vmx_support(void) {
    unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    eax = 1;
    ecx = 0;
    asm volatile("cpuid"
        : "=a" (eax),
          "=b" (ebx),
          "=c" (ecx),
          "=d" (edx)
        : "0" (eax), "2" (ecx)
        : "memory");
    vmx_bit = (ecx >> 5) & 1;
    if (vmx_bit == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to execute `vmx_support()` from **Method 1** inside a kernel module, Ubuntu freezes completely when I do `insmod vmx.ko` and I have to restart it to get it back. When I try to execute `vmx_support()` from **Method 2** inside the kernel module, it executes and shows `[VMX] vmx is supported.` on `dmesg | tail`.

Also, when I try to run `vmx_support()` from **Method 1** as a userspace program, it executes and prints `[VMX] vmx is supported.` as output to the console.

**Question:** Why does code from **Method 1** freeze Ubuntu whereas code from **Method 2** does not? Also, is there a safer way to test and debug code that uses inline assembly? (that is, avoid freezes for example)

Links to Makefile, kernel module and userspace program can be found here:

[Makefile](https://github.com/sbhTWR/vmm/blob/master/Makefile)

[vmx.c](https://github.com/sbhTWR/vmm/blob/master/vmx.c) (kernel module. The code from **method 2** is commented inside, uncomment it and comment the code from **method 1** to see how it works)

[vmx_sup.c](https://github.com/sbhTWR/vmm/blob/master/vmx_sup.c) (userspace program)

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with M1: 1) [Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html) 2) That same page tells you "For basic asm with non-empty assembler string GCC assumes the assembler block does not change any general purpose registers." And in case you didn't already know: "GCC does not parse basic asm’s AssemblerInstructions, which means there is no way to communicate to the compiler what is happening inside them." And just cuz is bothers me: That's an inefficient way to zero ecx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 has several problems, but the one that is causing it to hang is undoubtedly that it changes ebx without telling the compiler. In your user mode program, probably ebx doesn’t happen to have anything important in it, but in the kernel module, it apparently contains something critical.

Comment: Oh, I guess I have realized the importance of mentioning the output and input registers. Does Method 2 tell the compiler to the save the state of the registers in the output and input part of the asm statement before executing the asm instructions?